# call ElasticMQ with right_aws gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, right-aws

I have a rails application where I need to implement queuing system in it. Before that I want to see and understand how the queuing system works by creating a dummy rails application. 
So I am using ElaticMq with right_aws gem for that purpose.

I need to know how can I call the ElasticMQ from right_aws and create a queue with the help of right_aws gem. From their documentation I could not find any help.

So could you please input some ideas/suggestions for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to ElasticMQ server with right_aws gem. 
You need to pass the params for SqSGen2 with parameters as follows.

```
require "right_aws"
sqs = RightAws::SqsGen2.new("AKIA","bWksa23",:server=>"localhost",:port=>9324,:protocol=>"http")
queue = sqs.queue("awesome_queue")
queue.send_message("Hi Queue")
ss = queue.receive_messages(1,10)
puts ss #prints Hi Queue
puts queue.name #prints awesome_queue
```

Hope this helps.